# Reading and terminating stream in HttpClient 4

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm reading large documents from which I only need top 5%, can I do the following with HttpClient 4?

1. Request the page (get or post)
2. Read response as a stream
3. Feed it into SAX-based HTML parser "on the fly"
4. When certain HTML tag is detected - terminate the stream

Please note that HttpClient v. 4 is required - I cannot use v. 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ken from HttpClient mail list here's the answer

> Use the HttpEntity#getContent()
>   method, which returns an
>   java.io.InputStream, and pass that to
>   your SAX-based HTML parser.
>
> http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e122
>
> When you see the tag you need,
>   terminate the request via invoking the
>   HttpUriRequest#abort() method.
>
> http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e285