# How to use HttpClient to download continous data stream?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using **HttpURLConnection** to stream live content such as a radio broadcast.  However it seems that using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/) is a better option since it's well supported by Android and it's a better implementation. Also, there seems to be a logic for automatic reconnection from a lost connection.

My problem is that I can't get this to work. It's always hanging when calling **httpclient.execute(...)**.

What am I doing wrong?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://208.76.243.123:7100");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it in debugger and when it hangs, call break. Then find the thread that is executing your code and see in stack trace where exactly it blocked. You will see if it blocked on IO or something else is happening. With that data it will be easier to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure your server understands the HTTP protocol? (I assume yes, it sounds like you had a different client working).  It is possible the execute method is blocking because it has not seen a valid Response header yet.
2. You probably want `entity.getContent()` which will return a handle to a stream.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289629/reading-and-terminating-stream-in-httpclient-4) question.